# I am having troble understanding on_reaction_add [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to learn how to use [on_reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_reaction#discord.on_message_edit). I read the API and took 5 hours to research the topic.

I want to understand the topic more, so I ask for help from all of you.

Here is some code I tried to write:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if reaction.message.id == 876180955621113886-881237159665881098 and reaction.emoji == '1️⃣':
    reaction.message.channel.send("I got a message.")
```

The image of the message:[image: img]

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong because I don't get any output and explain how to check if someone reacts to a specific message?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_reaction_add` is only called if a message is in the bots cache (you need to send a message when the bot is online, then it's cached), you can't really guess what will be the next message ID, so hardcoding it inside the `on_reaction_add` event is not a good idea.

*You're also subtracting `881237159665881098` from `876180955621113886` which is `-5056204044767212`, however there are no negative IDs within discord...*

Another issue is that `.send` is a coroutine and it should be awaited.

---

You should use `on_raw_reaction_add` if you want to check for a specific message ID

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == YOUR_MESSAGE_ID and str(payload.emoji) == "1️⃣":
        channel = asyncio client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        await channel.send("I got a message")
```

Comment: Make a correction it is `await channel.send("I got a message")`

Comment: do you have a discord @Łukasz Kwieciński

Comment: I sent the requst